# Qt: making QHBoxLayout scrollable

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, layout

I have a `QHBoxLayout` horizontal layout with a lot of list widgets added to it.

And although I call `setMaximumWidth(300)` and `setMinimumWidth(300)` for the list widgets, once they don't fit on the window, they start to shrink.

I would like to have a scroll bar instead. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you put the Layout inside a parent widget, and that parent widget inside a QScrollArea.

[QScrollArea Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html)